# Creating triangle sequences given a format...why won't my triangles be displayed

Tags: java, design-patterns, numbers, pattern-matching, sequence

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my program. There should be four triangles printed as such:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2
1

        1
      2 1
    3 2 1
  4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1

1 2 3 4 5
  1 2 3 4
    1 2 3
      1 2
        1
```

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
public static String trianglePatterns(int limit) {
    // Triangle One
    for (int x = 1; x <= limit; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
            System.out.print(y + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    // Triangle Two
    while (limit > 0) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= limit; y++) {
            System.out.print(y + " ");
        }
        limit--;
        System.out.println("");
    }
    // Triangle Three
    for (int row = 1; row <= limit; row++) {
        for (int space = 7; space >= 0; space--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int num = 1; row >= 1; num--) {
            System.out.print(" " + num);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

I haven't even started the fourth one because I have no idea how to. My program will run and display the first two triangles correctly, but just doesn't include the third when I run it. What is causing the problem, and how do I begin the fourth triangle?

Comment: Why are you returning an empty String?

Comment: Did you try debugging? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to point out:

1. Your method can be void.
2. `System.out.print("\n");` = `System.out.println();`
3. You are modifying your `limit` variable. Is better to use copies on each loop

Here is my attempt:

```
public static void trianglePatterns(final int limit) {
    // Triangle One
    for (int x = 1; x <= limit; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
            System.out.print(y + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();

    // Triangle Two
    for (int x = limit; x > 0; x--) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
            System.out.print(y + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();

    // Triangle Three
    // first printint spaces of each row and then the numbers
    for (int x = 1; x <= limit; x++) {
        for (int space = (limit - x); space > 0; space--) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }

        for (int num = x; num > 0; num--) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
    // Triangle Four
    for (int x = limit; x >= 0; x--) {
        for (int space = (limit - x); space > 0; space--) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }

        for (int num = 1; num <= x; num++) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output for `trianglePatterns(5)`:

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5 

1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 
1 2 
1 

        1 
      2 1 
    3 2 1 
  4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 1 

1 2 3 4 5 
  1 2 3 4 
    1 2 3 
      1 2 
        1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are decreasing `limit` to 0 in triangle two loop, but break condition in the third one `row <= limit`. That's why it doesn't work.

As [phflack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5475891/phflack) noticed you don't need to cast integer to `String` while printing. Just pass `int` to `print()`. Read more in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).